# React Native: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have a React Native application that I cloned and after registering into the app on my simulator, I get this yellow error at the bottom of the screen which says:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is
>   not an object (evaluating 'data.Items')

I believe it has to be referencing one or all of these action creators in this file:

```
export function fetchPrefences({Key}) {
  return dispatch => {
    const url = `${endpoints.v2.INDIVIDUALS}/${Key}/preferences`;
    requester.sendGet(url).then(data => {
      const payload = helpers.sortPreferences(data);
      dispatch({
        type: types.SET_USER_PREFERENCES,
        payload,
      });
    });
  };
}

export function fetchTopics() {
  return dispatch => {
    requester.sendGet(endpoints.TOPICS_OF_CONCERN).then(data => {
      dispatch({
        type: types.SET_USER_TOPICS,
        payload: data.Items,
      });
    });
  };
}

export function handleUpdateTopics({topics, involved}, updateBoth = false) {
  return dispatch => {
    return requester
      .sendPut(endpoints.TOPICS_OF_CONCERN, {
        Items: topics,
      })
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.SET_USER_TOPICS,
          payload: data.Items,
        });
        if (updateBoth) {
          dispatch(handleUpdatePreferences({involved}));
        }
      });
  };
}
```

I have written asynchronous action creators in the past, but I can't see what is wrong with these. Is it that `data` is undefined? If so, my question would be, how is this possible if in other areas of the application `data` is being used with no obvious errors?

Comment: your `data` result is undefined ... it has nothing todo with your redux action

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli, thank you, that was part of my question. I am going to paste the action creator that references the endpoint. Can you suggest a way to troubleshoot why my `data` is coming back undefined?

Comment: One easy and straight forward way to check your api-endpoint is postman ... 
https://www.getpostman.com/ ...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli, go ahead and post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data result is undefined ... it has nothing todo with your redux action 
One easy and straight forward way to check your api-endpoint is [postman](http://getpostman.com) ...